# Adding multiple parameters to an else if statement?

Tags: javascript

Let me explain in more detail, I'm making a little sketch for my maths teacher that will calculate the missing sides and angles of a triangle. I have if/else/else if statements but I want an else if statement that will output something like "Check spelling" if none of the other statements are true. Basically, I want something that would do something like this (keep in mind I don't know how to program this yet)

```
// More code above
else if (side != "hypotenuse and adjacent"; "hypotenuse and opposite"; "opposite and adjacent") {
    confirm("Please check spelling.");
}
```

Can you see what I am trying to do? A previous variable is called side and it prompts the user to input which sides of the triangle they have, so the sketch can work out the angle. What if they have a spelling mistake and it doesn't match any of the parameters I set, how would I make it follow out this block of code if they don't match? I may have just over-complicated things here but if someone could tell me how to do this, it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `indexOf`:

```
 possibilities = ["hypotenuse and adjacent", "hypotenuse and opposite", "opposite and adjacent"]

 // so if side not in that array (the same as not in any of that values)
 if (possibilities.indexOf(side) == -1) {}
```

Comment: *Insert standard disclaimer of `Array:prototype:indexOf` needing polyfilled on IE8 and below*

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for a default statement if none of the others are matched? Wouldn't that just be an normal else statement? 
`else{//what you want here}`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of is to use `if`, `else if` and `else`. By using the `else` at the end, you won't need to write a huge check for the last line since all the previous.

`if (A) { A is true }
 else if (B) { Not A, but B }
 else if (C) { Not A or B, but C }
 else { Not A, B or C }`

An much nicer way to do this trick, is to use a `switch/case`, which is described [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp).

`switch(n) {
case A:
  A is true
  break;
case B:
  B is true
  break;
default:
  Not A or B
}`

However, if you only want the last check for "spell checking", I'd say @zishe has a neat answer to that.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to do this is to use jQuery function:

```
$.inArray(value, array)
```

which returns either positive index if the string can be found inside of array or -1 otherwise. So the solutions should be something like this:

```
var myArray = ["hypotenuse and adjacent", "hypotenuse and opposite", "opposite and adjacent"];

// more code above
else if($.inarray(side, myArray) == -1) {
    confirm("Please check spelling.");
}
```